# RpLIDAR unable to see black objects

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, navigation, lidar, hardware

I am working on a [ROSBOT](https://store.husarion.com/products/rosbot?variant=8835872292918) for a natural navigation project.

While working with RpLIDAR A2 version, I found that it does not sense thin black surfaces like black pants/trousers while at close range (less than 30 cms).

The screenshots of the RVIZ visualization of the robot is attached below

When the person at more than 80 cm from the LIDAR

[image: More than 80 cm from the LIDAR]

When the person at more than 50 cm from the LIDAR

[image: More than 50 cm from the LIDAR]

When the person reaches 30 cm from the LIDAR

[image: 30 cm from the LIDAR]

I tried debugging the code, but no errors in the code.

What are the methods we can use to improve sensing of the robot, can we do any hardware or software tuning to the RpLIDAR sensor to improve its sensing?

What are the likely errors causing this behaviour?

Comment: "What are the likely errors" Every sensor has its limitations and assumptions. Safety sensors (e.g. S300 from Sick) will definitely be able to see dark surfaces, but if you use a cheap sensor, you can't expect perfect data in all scenarios. The rplidar has an officiel minimal distance of 15cm (for white surfaces) and you are close to that limit.

Comment: @FooBar The sensor is RPLIDAR A2 version, the distance at which it is unable to detect the black surface was 30 cm. Upgrading the sensor to RPLIDAR A3 version is also resulting in a similar error. It is because of the black surface of the trouser because i can put a thicker black surface like a board the lidar detects the board

Answer (score 1):

LIDAR sensors rely on sending out a pulse of light it hitting an object and then traveling back to the sensor to detect it.

Black objects are often problematic because they absorb the light and not enough of the light gets back to the sensor. Depending on the technology that the LIDAR uses this can be more or less of a problem at different ranges but usually you will see errors start to occur near the edges of the working range, near or far depending on which limit your hitting.

The most obvious place to see this is in many of the longer range sensors they will spec the maximum range of the sensor for a given level of reflectivity of the object. Because for long range sensing the observable light bouncing back gets so weak as to be undetectable.

Also, black pants versus a "black" board can have very different surface properties which can change the absorbsion. And also remember that most LIDARs also work in infrared wavelengths so the "blackness" of the object is important in a different part of the spectrum than we can see.

And lastly I believe that the RPLIDAR uses a triangulation method which may be having trouble at closer ranges on oblique surfaces such as pant legs. The incident angle also significantly effects the reflectivity.